# TFS source branching strategy for product based company

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

We have an ERP solution, which had lot of modules. As a product company we are having several clients. 
The source control is maintained in TFS.

Now we customization for reach clients, what is the best way to manage the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truly I believe this depends on the language the application is built with:

**MVC**

In general, hopefully the business logic of all the applications is remaining the same, in that way the only differences would be in the view of each new instance. To manage these different views I would create sub-folders for each product.  But once again this is very generic as we don't know much about the current infrastructure.

**Edit**

Generally Speaking the branching stragey described here will work for most cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20878555/5268586.  For your application, if you are changing core logic located inside your application consider extending a base class for each client and overriding it's functionality to handle the new clients calculations.

i.e.
you have a class/file called CalcEngine
your client want to change some calculations, so make a new class Client1CalcEngine that will implement all of CalcEngine and override the one method/function.  These customer focused classes can then be bundled in your normal branches, as the implementation logic will decypther which to use.

Comment: Does it mean that maintaining different source code for each client is not a good idea ?

Comment: We had a talk with Microsoft regarding this , they are recommending to stick with Feature base system.